# Modulo function in c++, that behaves like mod in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I do a simulation with a lot of particles (up to 100000) in periodic domain(box), and in order particles to stay inside the box, I use modulo function with float or double numbers.

In `Matlab` everything works great with `mod` function. However in `C++` I found out, that function `fmod` is not completely equal to Matlab's `mod` function:

`mod(-0.5,10)=9.5`  - I want this result in `C++`

`fmod(-0.5,10)=-0.5` - I don't want this.

I, of course, can solve my problem with if statements. However, i think, it will affect efficiency (if statement in critical loop). Is there a way to implement this function without `if` statement? May be some other function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a conditional.  It will not meaningfully affect efficiency.

```
inline double realmod (x, y)
{
  result = fmod(x, y);
  return result >= 0 ? result : result + y;
}
```

`fmod()` calls assembly instruction `FPREM` which takes 16-64 cycles (according to the Pentium manual, http://www.intel.com/design/pentium/manuals/24143004.pdf).  The jump instructions for the conditional and the floating point addition only amount to 5 or so.

When your code has floating point division, you don't need to sweat the small stuff.

Comment: You can't compare efficiency just by counting the cycles for the instructions. If the branch predictor can't reliably predict which branch this will take it will have to flush the pipeline, which is one of the more costly things to consider. However, I agree. There's no reason to micro-optimize this.

Comment: Raymond Chen has covered the branch predictor before: [Non-classical processor behavior: How doing something can be faster than not doing it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/13/10533875.aspx). The cost of the division is much higher than the cost of the addition, so the effect will be less. But in the end, if you want to find out if you need to optimize this, you'll need to profile your simulation program.

Comment: what does Q stands for?

Comment: It works great for positive divisor (`y`) but not when the divisor is either `0` or negative, I posted a solution based on this that handles these cases.

Answer (score 3):

Either use `floor` and regular division:

```
float modulo(float a, float q)
{
    float b = a / q;
    return (b - floor(b)) * q;
}
```

or you can add the divisor to the result of `fmod` without branching:

```
float modulo(float a, float q)
{
    float m = fmod(a, q);
    return m + q * (m < 0.f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on **Matlab** `mod(a, m)` documentation and @QuestionC's answer -

A general solution that behaves exactly like **Matlab** - also for negative and zero divisor.

Tested against multiple values :

```
static inline double MatlabMod(double q, double m)
{
  if(m == 0)
    return q;

  double result = fmod(q, m);
  return ((result >= 0 && m > 0) || (q <= 0 && m < 0)) ? result : (result + m);
}
```

Tested with matlab for :

> `(q, m) -> result`
>
> (54, 321) -> 54
>
> (-50, 512) -> 462
>
> (54, -152) -> -98
>
> (-53, -500) -> -53
>
> (-500, 300) -> 100
>
> (-5000, 400) -> 200
>
> (-1000, -360) -> -280
>
> (500, 360) -> 140
>
> (1000, 360) -> 280
>
> (-1000, 360) -> 80
>
> (-5051, 0) -> -5051
>
> (512, 0) -> 512
>
> (0, 52) -> 0
>
> (0, -58) -> 0

Answer (score 1):

Just add the divisor to the number you want to keep in the interval before you apply the modulo operator:

```
return fmod(a+q,q);
```

this requires no branching at all.

If you have to worry about `a` exeeding `-q` between two updates, you can make it more robust by e.g.:

```
return fmod(a+q*10,q);
```

which would work for `a >= -10*q`

Comment: @QuestionC: If you assume, that `a` can have an abitrarily value, then yes, you'd have to write `fmod(fmod(a,q)+q,q);` But as far as I understand the application, this is about prticles, that move only a small distance between each simulation step. You can increase the tolerance by adding multiples of q though, like `fmod(a+10*q,q);`.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward with working for both floats and ints without any branching.

```
// b = MOD(a, m)
int a = a - m * floor(a / m) + m; 
int b = a - m * floor(a / m);
```